# Server Client in Java: could not start client

Tags: java, multithreading, virtual-machine, working-directory

I coded a tiny thread-based TCP Server and a Client, but I could not start the Client. Java VM seems to have problems.

```
chris@chris-UX31E:~/workspace/verteilte/build$ java Client localhost 9000 9002
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.
    at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
    at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1115)
```

Whats wrong with the environment/working directory?

Comment: Check if you have read access to all the directories up to the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record: A restart solved the problem.